# Servidor Glassfish com Dockerfile

Tags: docker

Boa noite pessoal!!

Estou com o seguinte problema:

Preciso subir um container contendo o servidor Glassfish, a imagem foi gerada a partir de um Dockerfile, no entanto ao executar o container contendo essa imagem, no ultimo passo, ou seja, realizar o deploy da aplicação, depois de algum tempo o container finaliza sua execução.

Segue o corpo do Dockerfile

```html
FROM ubuntu:latest
COPY ./glassfish/ /usr/local/
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y make git openjdk-8-jdk
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
ENV GLASSFISH_HOME /usr/local/glassfish4/glassfish 
ENV PATH $JAVA_HOME/bin:$GLASSFISH_HOME/bin:$PATH 
RUN mkdir /app
COPY ./mercado/target/mercado.war /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN asadmin start-domain domain1 && \
    asadmin deploy /app/mercado.war
```

---

Enfim preciso que o container fique executando para que a aplicação não pare sua execução.

Não consegui identificar o erro no Dockerfile, mas se puderem me ajudar desde já agradeço a atenção!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá @john.sousa, então cara, um container é feito para morrer, o problema não está na sua ultima linha e sim no entendimento da coisa, ok? Eu sugiro dar uma estudada na documentação do Docker e principalmente como fazer ele funcionar em modo Daemon. Aprendendo isso você já resolve seu problema. Docker parece difícil, mas, é bastante simples e vai te ajudar muito posteriormente.

A ultima linha do seu script use CMD e aponte para um arquivo de Entrypoint, neste arquivo você roda `asadmin start-domain domain1 asadmin deploy /app/mercado.war`

Outra coisa, eu verifiquei no seu script que vc copia o diretório do Glassfish e aponta a variável de ambiente para glassfish4, acredito que você terá um problema aí quando conseguir rodar seu script corretamente.

Alem disso, existem imagens já do glassfish 4 (glassfish) ou do java 8 (openjdk:8-jdk-alpine) não precisa fazer todo aquele trabalho de instalação e configuração de variáveis.

Por fim para você me avaliar muito bem essa resposta (mas, ainda assim considere ler a documentação)

Você deve rodar isso dentro da pasta onde está o Dockerfile
`docker build -t mercado:1.0 .`

Esse comando irá construir um novo container.

`docker run --net=host mercado:1.0`

Este comando irá rodar a aplicação e setar todas a portas automaticamente.

Alguns links bacana para aprender os conceitos do docker seguem abaixo: 
https://blog.geekhunter.com.br/docker-na-pratica-como-construir-uma-aplicacao
https://www.mundodocker.com.br/o-que-e-docker/